# RDS Oracle snapshot stuck at creating - 0% when copied to a different AWS region

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, copy, snapshot, rds

I'm trying to copy a DB snapshot from one AWS region to another, but the snapshot is always stuck at creating, with 0% progress. I've been able to copy and restore other DB snapshots between the two regions, but any snapshot from this specific Oracle DB gets stuck every time.

We can copy it in the same region, but cross-region will not work. We haven't tried snapshotting and copying any other Oracle databases, but we had success with a Postgres snapshot. The DB is pretty big, 200GB of storage, but we left the snapshot overnight and it still did not get past 0%.

Has anyone experienced this, or have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: So, you already have a snapshot but are unable to copy it to another region? Or are you unable to take the snapshot in the first place?

Comment: We were able to take the snapshot, it's just copying it to a new region that isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer back from AWS support - if the snapshot is created from a running database, and that database is deleted, copying the snapshot to a different region can break. Copying the snapshot into the same region, and then copying it into the new region, works.

Seems as though the snapshot retains knowledge of where it came from, and if it came from a DB, it tries to get backup information from that DB. If the snapshot was created from another snapshot, it doesn't attempt to access any database for information.

TLDR; copy the snapshot into the same region, copy that new snapshot into the new region.